# possible scope issue c++

Tags: c++, oop, vector

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
class t{
    public:
        t();
        void updateSize();
        int getSize();
        void insert();
        int get(int a);
    private:
        int size;
        vector<int> v;

};

t::t(){
    size =0;
}
void t::updateSize(){
    size++;
}
int t::getSize(){
    return size;
}
int t::get(int a){
    return v[a];
}
 void t::insert(){
    v.push_back(size);

    ++size;
}

int main(){
   t xa;
   xa.insert();
   xa.insert();
   xa.insert();
       xa.insert();
   cout<<xa.get(3);//expect to output 3 but instead outputs 0


   return 0;
}
```

this code is supposed to increment the size every time I call insert, and put an integer of with the value of that size in a vector at the same index of that size. But for some reason it does not put the updated size into my vector.

Answer (score 4):

You're inserting 3 elements but you're reading the 4th (since the indexing is 0 based).

Comment: actually forget what I just said

Answer (score 0):

The program you posted will print "3". Proof read your code.

Comment: I think the OP just changed his program in his question when he saw his mistake -- which he should not -- judging on Eugen's answer.